# Экспорт БД и импорт БД на другом устройстве, с возможностью переключения между несколькими БД

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Есть приложение, записывает в БД параметры о состоянии батареи телефона постоянно. Допустим пользователи экспортируют свои БД мне (экспорт БД я нашел), возможен ли выбор и использование нескольких БД (импортированных) в приложении? При этом, чтобы на моем устройстве продолжалась запись параметров батареи моего телефона в мою БД.

Comment: Можно. БД это просто файл. Можно их передавать и подключаться к скаченной откуда-то.

Comment: а если у меня есть несколько импортированных БД, как мне обратится к определенной из них не используя замену существующей на устройстве?

Comment: У файлов БД должны быть разные имена и/или они должны быть в разных папках. После этого просто подключайтесь к БД по имени файла

Comment: Этого так же можно добиться разбиением на схемы. И все будет в одной базе и даже переключаться не надо.

Comment: А можно поподробней про схемы. Может быть есть где почитать?